# fiddle works but not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Fiddle:[fiddle](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/115394849300833601650/albums/5803757570985447105/5803757623376512034)

code:[pic](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/115394849300833601650/albums/5803757570985447105/5803757623376512034)

< /body>
< /html>

Comment: Please provide the code in text format. Showing an incomplete screenshot won't help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery in your fiddle, but you have to make sure you have jQuery loaded in your HTML code. This is usually the case where code works on jsFiddle but not on your own site.

Comment: i have, is this the right way?                                   <script type="text/javascript" src= "G:\portfolio\New folder\jquery-1.8.2.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(function......</script>

Comment: Yes, if the one above is the official jQuery file, then it will work. And can you please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark next to it?